# How to Show Short Post Information inside Page Template in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a page template where I'm showing a list of custom post types using WP_Query:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'jana_usa',
    'post_status' => array('publish', 'pending'),
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
$posts = '';
if($query->have_posts()) {
    $posts .= '<div class="test-posts">';
    while ($query->have_posts()) {
        $query->the_post();
        $posts .= '<article class="test-post">';
        $posts .= '<h5>' . get_the_title() . '</h5>';
        $posts .= '</article>';

    }
    $posts .= '</div>';
    wp_reset_postdata();
    echo $posts;
} else {
    echo '<div>' . __("Sorry, No Posts Found", "_themename") . '</div>';
}
```

I want to add button "View More" for every article, it's not a problem, the problem is I want when user click button he will be redirected to a new page template where title and excerpt of clicked article will be shown.

So my question how can I show this short information of post that was clicked on separate page template? How can I get article ID that was clicked in my page template?

For example, I will create page template:

```
<?php 
/*
Template Name: Short Post Page
*/
get_header(); ?>
<main role="main">
   <?php echo get_the_title(get_the_ID()); ?>
   <?php echo get_the_excerpt(get_the_ID()); ?>
</main>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

But it will not be right, because I can't get ID of article that was clicked before.

Comment: Do you still need the articles to have full pages as well as the "short" pages? If so, can you explain why you want to create the short pages, so we might be able to suggest the best way to do it that will work what you are trying to do?

Comment: @FluffyKitten Yes, I also need single pages for custom posts. Actually, I'm creating website for users that can post their own adverts in frontend. I have login and register form, also user can post their advert, now I want to add possibility to edit their own adverts. Users have account page, where they can see list of adverts that they posted and button for every post "Edit advert", after clicking they will be redirected to a new page with the form. I'm using wp_update_post() where I need to write ID of the post that should be updated. That's it.